# How to assign several cores/threads/tasks to an application that runs in parallel and is going to be run from the command line on MacOS laptop?

Tags: macos, matlab, command-line, parallel-processing, slurm

I have an application that can run commands in parallel. This application can work on a cluster using SLURM to get the resources, then internally, I assign each of the tasks I require to be performed by a different CPU/worker. Now, I want to run this application on my laptop (macOS) through the command line, the ***same*** code (except for the SLURM part) works fine with the only difference being that it is only performing one task at a time.

I have run code in parallel in MATLAB using the commands parcluster, parfor, etc. In this code, I can get up to 16 workers to work in parallel on my laptop.

I was hoping there is a similar solution for any other application that is not MATLAB to run other code in parallel, especially to assign the resources. Then my application itself is built to manage them.

If it is of any help, I run my application from the command line as follows:

```
chmod +x ./bin/OpenSees
./bin/OpenSees Run.tcl
```

I have read about GNU parallel or even using SLURM on my laptop, but I am not sure if these are the best (or feasible) solutions.

I tried using GNU parallel:

```
chmod +x ./bin/OpenSees 
parallel -j 4 ./bin/OpenSees ::: Run.tcl
```

but it continues doing one at a time, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: GNU Parallel is great! Give it a try!

Comment: Thanks, @CrisLuengo! Do you know which set of commands is best suited to achieve my goal?

Comment: I tried using: `chmod +x ./bin/OpenSees
parallel -j 4 ./bin/OpenSees ::: Run.tcl` but it still continues doing one at a time, do you have any suggestions?

Comment: With that command you run your script once, I guess. Is it the script that starts all the jobs? If so, it is the script that needs to use Parallel to run the tasks. It is not magic, it will not magically fix your script for you.

Comment: My original command is executing OpenSees, a software with parallel computing capabilities, it is TCL based, so  I execute `Run.tcl` using Opensees. This file is where I write my code in TCL and inside I have parallel computing commands that manage the processors, however, the problem is that in my laptop these commands have only access to 1 processor. I believe that what GNU parallel is just trying to run OpenSees several times at the same time, which could be another solution, but it doesn't fix the problem of allowing OpenSees to have access to more than 1 processor.

Comment: If OpenSees doesn’t do parallel computing on your machine, you need to ditch it. Use GNU Parallel instead.